# wordpress - page not loading (404) even if it's there

Tags: php, 404-error

I have a major issue with WordPress.

I created a page and it keeps saying "page not found" when trying to navigate to it.

The page is definitely there.

I tried removing and re-creating .htaccess file with no luck.

I tried it both manually and automatically with the permalink trick, none worked.

The error log doesn't show anything and neither the access log.

What else can it be? the root of the website works, is when I try to reach any other page that fails.

I don't know that else to try, so any help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: What's the "permalinks trick" exactly?

Comment: settings - permalinks - changing, saving and changing it back. It should rewrite the htaccess file

Comment: and does it actually rewrite the .htaccess?

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and can you verify that it's working?

Comment: There's some missing information here: is it just this page or do all pages give a 404? Is this a standard page that you created in the admin area, or do you mean something else by page? Can you provide an example? Has this always been the case or is this a new problem? What is your htaccess?
Is your server using Apache or Nginx? Do post permalinks work? What are your permalink settings? All of these questions are important, please edit your question with the necessary details, even if you don't think they're relevant